# Variable value is false before and after an if block but is unexpectedly hitting the if block as if it was true

Tags: php, post, if-statement

I would like to update my database accordingly based on whether `$_POST['Subscribe']` is `true` or `false`. My `if` statement does not work as expected. When the value of `$_POST['Subcribe']` is `false`, it does not unsubscribe the user from the database.

```
if($_POST['Subscribe'] == true) 
{ 
    // Subscribe 
}
else 
{
    // Unsubscribe
}
```

---

I discovered that when `$_POST['Subscribe']`  is `false` it does not hit the `else` block as expected.

```
$post_beforeifstatement = $_POST['Subscribe']; 

if($_POST['Subscribe'] == true) 
{ 
    // Subscribe 
    $subscribestatus = true; 
} 
else 
{
    // Unsubscribe 
    $subscribestatus = false; 
} 

$post_afterifstatement = $_POST['Subscribe'];
```

Upon looking at the values, it seems that `$_POST['Subscribe']` is `false` (as expected) before and after the `if` block, however `$subscribestatus` is `true`.

- Is there a better way to debug this?
- Is there something I am obviously doing wrong?

Comment: Debug and show us using `var_dump($_POST['Subscribe']);`. Make sure type is boolean and not string. Using strict comparison `===`.

Comment: You cannot test a post field against a boolean. It's value can only be string or array. Use `isset($_POST['Subscribe'])`.

Comment: `$_POST['Subscribe']` bring the value as STRING not boolean. Try `if($_POST['Subscribe'] == 'true') { ...`

Comment: Show how the `$_POST['Subscribe']` is false

Comment: I'm not sure if var_dump can be used as this is an AJAX file? (i.e. it is handling this stuff without being in it's own window)

Comment: @machineaddict `isset($_POST['Subscribe'])` returns as true

Comment: You can't compare string with Boolean. You should use `$_POST['Subscribe'] == 'true'` or `isset($_POST['Subscribe'])`.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent if I try `if($_POST['Subscribe'] == 'true') { ... ` it doesn't *seem* to hit either block. `$subscribestatus` is unset.

Comment: I'm aware I could probably be debugging this in a better way but I'm not sure how since this is an AJAX file.

Comment: @Eilidh: If you pushed that button, yes it does. I gave you a "bigger" answer. Look below.

Comment: @Eilidh: Show us the ajax code. Also, you can debug ajax requests with a tool like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: how is `$_POST['Subscribe']` presented? thru a button? a checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['Subscribe']` cannot be checked against a `boolean` value.

```
if($_POST['Subscribe'] == 'true')   
{
    // Subscribe
}
else 
{
    // Unsubscribe
}
```

This compares `$_POST['Subscribe']` to a `string` rather than a `boolean`.

(With thanks to the commenters.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form is like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="texte" />
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe" />
    <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

You can test which submit button has been pushed:

```
if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) {
    // do subscribe
}
elseif (isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])) {
    // do unsubscribe
}
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, I am looking at the value of `$_POST['Subscribe']` to determine if it is `true` or `false`. I do not have two `$_POST` values to look at.

Comment: @Eilidh: I'm no wizard to guess your ajax code (as you didn't posted it), but if you send the subscribe and unsubscribe key when they are pushed, the code above works. This code doesn't have to be the solution, but it might bring an idea how to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with these code** :

```
if($_POST['Subscribe'] === true) 
{ 
    echo "Subscribe ";
    // Subscribe
}
else 
{
    echo "Unsubscribe ";
    // Unsubscribe
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope this will help you

```
if($_POST['Subscribe'] == true) 
{ 
    // Subscribe 
}
if($_POST['Subscribe'] == false) 
{
    // Unsubscribe
}
```